# How to make a dispenser shoot infinite creeper eggs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was making a cool armor and etc. So now i need a creeper spawner for my game which shoots infinitly for my test do you have a code for it?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: @Frank but its too complicted! i tried all codes!

Comment: If it's so complicated, why would you expect to get help, for free, when we haven't seen you try anything?  We don't mind helping, but Arqade works so much better when we see that you have tried first, at least.

Comment: What the heck? Since when do we demand that a question poster try stuff on their own first? If he knew what to try, he wouldn't be asking! And "for free" shouldn't come into it at all. We answer questions to give back to the community that answers ours. Answer or don't, but don't give the guy guff.

Comment: @watonis I've not messed with command blocks much, but this might be some help http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Command_block#1.7_uses

Comment: @Fambina So you don't mind being treated like a code dispenser? I do. If they're not going to try, that's literally what downvoting is for.

Comment: @Fambina, in fact "shows no research effort" is a hard-written reason for downvoting, which lowers the chance of a question being answered, and eventually leads it to the low quality queue.

Answer (score 3):

I have a simple solution:

1. **Place another dispenser** (2nd dispenser) a few blocks away and make sure it is facing the way you want it to face. Fill it with the Creeper spawn eggs.
2. Place a command block which will **clone** the 2nd dispenser to the first one. (/clone X1 Y1 Z1 X2 Y2 Z2 X Y Z).
3. Build a redstone clock that will power the command block.
4. Enjoy your infinite amount of spawn eggs!

Comment: @DaQuihibo OH I FORGOT IT i gonna really use it!

Answer (score 1):

Although there might be "Keyword: **MIGHT**", off the top of my head, there is no ***SURVIVAL*** way to make an infinite creeper egg stream. You might be able to with commands, and you are definitely able to with [Not Enough Items](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1279956-chickenbones-mods), but as far as I know, there is no way to do that.

Comment: There isn't even a way to get the spawn egg item in vanilla Minecraft :)